# Error templates with functions in C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the calling to the function.
After I debug it said that 'boobleSort : undeclared identifier' and 'type short unexpected'.

```
main()
{
  short arr[] = {2,10,-15,20};
  short size = 4;
  bobbleSort<short, short*>(size, arr);
}

template<class FIRST_TYPE, class SECOND_TYPE>
void bobbleSort(FIRST_TYPE size, SECOND_TYPE arr)
{
  arr[2]++;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Move the definition of `bobbleSort` to before `main`.

Comment: You fix it by defining the template before it gets used.

Comment: You don't need to specify the types when calling `bubbleSort`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to return 0 from the main. This compiles and runs for me. Make sure to add some error checking to the bobbleSort since the arr may not have 3 elements.

```
template<class FIRST_TYPE, class SECOND_TYPE>
void bobbleSort(FIRST_TYPE size, SECOND_TYPE arr)
{
    arr[2]++;
}

int main()
{
    short arr[] = { 2,10,-15,20 };
    short size = 4;
    bobbleSort(size, arr);

    return 0; 
}
```